# How to read/ get the content of a word document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

Im trying to pull the content of a word document, when I get the content of it all I get is symbols

Ex:

```
�w%�=���^i7+���-d&�0�A�6�l4��L60#�Ò�S
O����X�
```

I'm trying to decode the content but doesn'w work. any ideas on how to do this.

```
const decoderr = new TextDecoder();
const decoder  = new TextEncoder();

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', './file.docx');
client.onreadystatechange = function() { 
  console.log(client.responseText);
  const byteArray = decoder.encode(client.responseText)
  console.log(byteArray);
  console.log(decoderr.decode(byteArray));
}
client.send();
```

Comment: Find a library on github that will parse it.

Comment: The `docx` files are just a bunch of zipped files, and those files tend to be XML. I have no idea why you would expect a file, containing formatting information amongst others should somehow be ascii.

Answer (score 0):

Those are "Replacement Characters".

They are often used when the font you are viewing the text in does not contain a character for the Unicode symbol that was received.

First thing to try is changing the document font a few times to see if any of your system fonts include the character! Hope this helps.